# IBM WCM menu component iteration

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-wcm

Hi i have an scenario to read site area content in result design 1 and then content inside that site area in result design 2 in ascending order. for this i am using menu component but it is reading all site area content and content inside site area only in result design 1. How i can read sit area in result design 1 and content inside site area in result design 2. I tried with navigator component but in menu component it is not working because i need the content response in sorting order.

Comment: Can you provide a summary of your menu component configuration and some more detail? As I recall, menu components do not have result design fields, so I'm a bit confused by the question. Please try to clarify a bit more. Navigator components are only for generating navigation based on site areas (not for bringing back lists of content).

Comment: i have attached a list presentation in menu component in which i took two results designs 1 and 2 to read the content attached with menu component. In menu component i have added categories to search the content through query parameter.  so when i am searching the content so in this case i need to read sitearea content in result design1 and child content in result design2.